# Block a Subdomain in Windows Firewall

Tags: networking, dns, firewall

Gamespy is ceasing its Master Server support for many games at the end of May, including Crysis 1, Wars, and 2. I have worked with Crysis 1 and Crysis Wars for a very long time, and now the entire community is leaning on me to develop a solution to no master-server support.

*What the Master Server does:*
The Master Server basically receives 'heartbeats' from all the gameservers in the game and sorts them into a list, enabling users to connect to them. It interfaces with the Gamespy account database to retrieve profile IDs in order for gameserver administrators to administrate their server correctly.

I have a hypothesis that the master server is not connected to the database server in any way, meaning that the player accounts will stay although the master server will disappear. This means that we can still manually add gameservers to the server list.

I have tried testing this hypothesis by blocking the IP of crysiswars.master.gamespy.com in Windows Firewall (With Advanced Security), both Outbound and Inbound, but it however still lets the data through.

How can I block the Master Server in order to test my hypothesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is to add an entry in your hosts file that looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1    crysiswars.master.gamespy.com
```

What this will do is override whatever crysiswars.master.gamespy.com is pointing to to your local pc, effectively blocking all communication.

You can find the hosts file at the following location:

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc
```

and requires administrative privleges to edit, so make sure you open your texteditor with administrative privileges before opening the file.

Once you save, you can test it immediately by pinging to crysiswars.master.gamespy.com. It'll give 127.0.0.1 instead of 69.10.30.248.

Note, the hosts file does not have support for wildcards. So each domain or variation has to be specified as a row with the same (or different) ip address.

Comment: I've heard about Hosts before. Do I have to reboot my computer before the change applies?

Comment: As written in my answer: `Once you save, you can test it immediately by pinging to crysiswars.master.gamespy.com` Save the document and the changes are immediate. You can even keep the editor open with the file, make a change, save, test, return to the document and make more changes.

Comment: LPCChip- It required me to reboot in order to apply the changes; I could still get a 100ms+ ping until I rebooted, where I got a <1ms ping.

Comment: Changing the hostsfile is instant, but it is possible gamespy needed to be restarted, in order to refetch the ip address. I can only say that after a hostsfile change, a new DNS lookup will give the new ip directly after that. But if a service/program is not doing a DNS lookup, it obviously won't get the new ip address.