# Blocking an IP in Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, dns, firewall

I am attempting to block a connection to a games' masterserver [(see this for more information, including why I am trying to do so)](https://superuser.com/questions/739273/block-a-subdomain-in-windows-firewall/739313?noredirect=1#comment950986_739313), but however redirecting the DNS has not worked, so I am trying to now block the IP in Windows Firewall.

I have tried to create a simple Outbound rule to block the IP (69.10.30.248), but I am still able to ping the IP.
I've also tried Comodo firewall, but it however was not practical and caused the Windows GUI to completely freeze (including Task Manager), so I was forced to disable it via Safe Mode and uninstall it.

Why is the Windows Firewall IP block failing to block the IP (*Remember: Outbound only*), and how can I make the IP block work?

I am on Windows 7 Home Premium SP1, and Windows Firewall is on its Public profile:

[image]

Comment: Is firewall enabled for the public profile?

Comment: shinjijai- Yes it is.

Comment: Can you post your Windows Firewall with Advanced Security on Local Computer screen?

Comment: Edited image into the OP.

Comment: Odd, I just did a quick test and it worked for me (`general failure` when I tried to ping that IP). My settings are as follow: `General tab` > Enabled and block the conneciton. `Program and Services` > All programs that meet the specified condition. `Computers` > nothing checked. `Advanced` > check mark on all profiles (for testing purpose). `Scope` > Local IP address > Any IP address; Remote IP Address > `These IP Address` > 69.10.30.248. Protocol > Any.

Comment: Hmm, what OS are you using and what security profile is in use?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional SP1 and the rule was applied to all profiles. Unfortunately I don't have Windows 7 Home to test it on.

Comment: I did a quick upgrade to Windows 7 Ultimate (MSDN- I was planning to do so for a few weeks, but never got round to it), but however the issue persists.

Comment: I re-added the rule, and it now works (I'm getting General Failure). If you put your solution as an answer, I'll upvote it and accept it as the answer for this question. It'll also be worth mentioning that you need Windows 7 Professional or higher to do so.

Comment: Good to know about the Windows 7 Professional requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a quick test and it worked for me (general failure when I tried to ping that IP). My settings are as follow:

`General tab > Enabled and block the conneciton.`

`Program and Services > All programs that meet the specified condition.`

`Computers > nothing checked. Advanced > check mark on all profiles (for testing purpose).`

`Scope > Local IP address > Any IP address
         Remote IP Address > These IP Address > 69.10.30.248.`

`Protocol > Any`